# Contract deployment by other contract not returning the address

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I have a main contract deployed that exposes a method `mintSubContract`:

```
function mintSubContract(uint256 initialAmount) public returns (address) {
    SubContract sub = new SubContract(msg.sender, address(this));
    address subAddress = address(sub);
    if (initialAmount > 0) {
        _transfer(msg.sender, address(sub), initialAmount);
    }
    _subAddresses.push(address(sub));
    sub.mint(msg.sender, 0);
    return address(sub);
}
```

When I call this function in Hardhat's `ethers` like so:

```js
const subContract address = await mainContract.mintSubContract(500);
```

At first I expected `subContract` to hold the address. Now because that contract method is not (and can't be) a view, it actually holds a transaction.

Right now this is how I end up getting the address of the deployed sub-contract:

```js
const transaction = await mainContract.mintSubContract(500);
const result = await transaction.wait();
```

At this point the value in `result` is this:

```json
{
  "to": "0x0a", /* The main contract address */
  "from": "0x01", /* The sender of the transaction */,
  "more keys": "That are irrelevant at this point for this matter (I think)",
  "events": [
    { /* The transfer event in case there is one */
      "transactionIndex": 0,
      "blockNumber": 18,
      "transactionHash": "0x...",
      "address": "0x...",
      "topics": [ /* ... */ ],
      "data": "0x01e4",
      "logIndex": 0,
      "blockHash": "0x...",
      "args": [
        "0x01", /* The sender of the transaction */
        "0x0b", /* The newly deployed contract */
        {
          "type": "BigNumber",
          "hex": "0x01f4" /* The amount (500) */
        }
      ],
      "event": "Transfer",
      "eventSignature": "Transfer(address,address,uint256)"
    },
    { /* <------ This event has no name! */
      "transactionIndex": 0,
      "blockNumber": 18,
      "transactionHash": "0x...",
      "address": "0x0b", /* The newly deployed contract */
      "topics": [ /* ... */ ],
      "data": "0x",
      "logIndex": 1,
      "blockHash": "0x4569d6a315dad67d218e3dc2055467da7bd69b6cd6c5c49084c11a6976286dd1"
    }
  ]
}
```

In this scenario we have an `initialAmount` so we have a `Transfer` event in that transaction (from ERC20 specs). The other event is what I suppose is the Contract Creation. At this point I'm just guessing. Right now I get the address of the newly created contract like this:

```js
const subContractEvent = result.events.find(e => e.event === undefined); // Get the event with no name
const subContractAddress = subContractEvent.address;
```

This feels very hacky and I can think of a few ways it could go wrong. So my question is: Is there a better way? If this is the only way, does it even make sense to try to return the address of the subContract from the `mintSubContract()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, indeed, a faster way: use 2 different contract interaction type, one static call (to get the returned value, will **not** mine the transaction) and one regular transaction (as you were doing, but you can then discard the wait() result):

```
const address_of_sub = await mainContract.callStatic.mintSubContract(500); //no state change/no gas
await mainContract.mintSubContract(500); //the actual tx
```

See for instance this discussion in ethers repo: https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/1188

And `callStatic` ethersjs docs: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#contract-callStatic

This is perhaps more clear in web3js, where you have a send() and call() methods (i.e. `my_contract.foo.call(args)` and `my_contract.foo.send(args)`).